# Nodemon seems to be "gone" since passport implementation

Tags: node.js, express

i just was testing passport and for better understanding i tried to implement the example from passport into my app.
But since i have done that i cannot start nodemon app.js (node app.js is working). The Console keeps telling me:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\nodemon.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

So this is my package JSON and app.js:

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "jade": "*",
    "less": "*",
    "connect": "*",
    "connect-flash": "*",
    "lingua": "*",
    "mysql": "*",
    "now": "*",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-local": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.x",
    "npm": "*"
  }
}
```

.

> app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express         = require('express'),
    flash           = require('connect-flash'),
    routes          = require('./routes'),
    user            = require('./routes/user'),
    http            = require('http'),
    path            = require('path'),
    lingua          = require('lingua'),
    passport        = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;


// Passport Test Setup
var users = [
    { id: 1, username: 'bob', password: 'secret', email: 'bob@example.com' }
    , { id: 2, username: 'joe', password: 'birthday', email: 'joe@example.com' }
];


function findById(id, fn) {
    var idx = id - 1;
    if (users[idx]) {
        fn(null, users[idx]);
    } else {
        fn(new Error('User ' + id + ' does not exist'));
    }
}

function findByUsername(username, fn) {
    for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        if (user.username === username) {
            return fn(null, user);
        }
    }
    return fn(null, null);
}

// Passport session setup.
//   To support persistent login sessions, Passport needs to be able to
//   serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.  Typically,
//   this will be as simple as storing the user ID when serializing, and finding
//   the user by ID when deserializing.
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done (null, id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {

    done (null, id);
});

// Use the LocalStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, a username and password), and invoke a callback
//   with a user object.  In the real world, this would query a database;
//   however, in this example we are using a baked-in set of users.
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        // asynchronous verification, for effect...
        process.nextTick(function () {

            // Find the user by username.  If there is no user with the given
            // username, or the password is not correct, set the user to `false` to
            // indicate failure and set a flash message.  Otherwise, return the
            // authenticated `user`.
            findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
                if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); }
                return done(null, user);
            })
        });
    }
));


var app = express();

// configure Express
app.configure(function() {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(lingua(app, {
        defaultLocale: 'en-US',
        path: __dirname + '/languages',
        storageKey: 'lang'
    }));
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat'}));
    app.use(flash());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});


// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

// app.get
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { user: req.user, message: req.flash('error')});
});



// Simple route middleware to ensure user is authenticated.
//   Use this route middleware on any resource that needs to be protected.  If
//   the request is authenticated (typically via a persistent login session),
//   the request will proceed.  Otherwise, the user will be redirected to the
//   login page.
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/login')
}


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Does anyone have an idea what might have gone wrong?

regards

Comment: What this says: `npm install nodemon -g` ?

Comment: Yep! Thx you wer're abesolutely right. but this is strange anyways, i have used nodemon with this project all the time before and the server was running until 3 minutes before the problem occurred o_O...